# attributes used before defined in a module

Tags: python, class, module, method-resolution-order

Here is the code:

```
#a.py
ALL_FUNC = [bar, foo]  #a list containing all the functions defined in this module

def bar():
    pass

def foo():
    pass
```

Then, I run it like this:
$ python a.py
NameError: name 'bar' is not defined

The error means, `bar` is not defined when `ALL_FUNC = [bar, foo]` is executed. But why can't the interpreter find the function `bar` in the module? Just because `bar` is defined after `ALL_FUNC`?

Look at this, here is a python class,

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar()

    def bar(self):
        pass

a = A()
```

Apparently, the above code will run without any error, but `bar` in `A` is also defined after where it's accessed (in `__init__`), why `self.bar()` can be found without any error?

**Follow Up**

Here is another module,

```
#b.py
def bar():
    print k  #well, apparently this line will result in an error
def foo():
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo()
```

Then run it like this,

```
$ python b.py
```

NO ERROR! Why? `bar` is supposed to result in an error, isn't it? Just because it's not used in `__main__`, so the error isn't detected? But `bar`'s definition is executed, right?

Answer (score 2):

The interpreter executes the script from top to bottom.

`def` is an executable statement. Any name created by `def` (such as `foo` and `bar` in your first example) does not exist until the relevant `def` statement has been executed.

Now to your second example: the name `self.bar()` is resolved when `__init__()` is *called*, and it's called *after* the entire class definition has been seen.

Comment: So, when I run `python a.py`, the code in a.py will be interpreted line by line in order? No matter a function is used or not?

Comment: @Alcott: Exactly. Furthermore, the same name can refer to different functions at different points in your script.

Comment: Well, I must be confused that, in C++'s template class, only those used functions will get instantiated and their code will be generated, but in python's module, all lines of code will be interpreted and executed, right?

Comment: @Alcott: Pretty much. In Python, everything is dynamic and things like `class`, `def` etc are actually executable statements.

Comment: @Alcott There are no templates in Python, not even remotely. Yes, all code is executed, but note that in this context, function declarations are "executed" only in that a default arguments are evaluated and the function object is created, nothing more. But generally, yes.

Comment: @delnan, don't quite get `function declarations are "executed" only in that a default arguments are evaluated and the function object is created`, could you plz elaborate on that?

Comment: @Alcott: Take a look at http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/python_functions_def.html

Comment: @Alcott For instance, when the lines `def f(x=some_func()): print(x)` are executed, `some_func` is called and the result is stored, but not printed.

Answer (score 2):

*But why can't the interpreter find the function bar in the module? Just because bar is defined after ALL_FUNC?*

Because the code is executed in the order it appears in the file. Where you try to assign the values to `ALL_FUNC` the function definitions haven't been executed.

*but bar in A is also defined after where it's accessed (in `__init__`), why `self.bar()` can be found without any error?*

Because `__init__` has been called after the class has been defined. Your class is instantiated by `a = A()`, after the class definition.

---

**Response to Follow up**

*Why? `bar` is supposed to result in an error, isn't it? Just because it's not used in `__main__`, so the error isn't detected? But bar's definition is executed, right?*

If you called `bar()` you'd get a `NameError`. When you defined the `bar` function, the function code was *interpreted*, not *executed*. I'm not sure whether this would ever pick up anything other than `SyntaxError`s, but definitely not `NameError`s.

However, `bar` won't always result in an error. Consider:

```
>>> def bar():
...   print(k)
...
>>> bar()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in bar
NameError: global name 'k' is not defined
>>> k = "Foo"
>>> bar()
Foo
```